# Can I reuse the deleted project ID on google cloud platform? By the way, I found something wrong in google cloud platform docs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

*To interact with Google Cloud resources, you must provide the identifying project information for every request. A project can be identified in the following ways:
Project name: the customized name you chose when you created the project, or when you activated an API that required you to create a project ID. Note that you can't reuse the project name of a deleted project.
Project ID: a unique identifier for your project, composed of the project name and a randomly assigned number.
Project number: a number that's automatically generated by the server and assigned to your project.*
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects

As I know, project name can be changed whenever I hope, and I have tested that even I can use the exist project's name as a new project name.

Comment: I am not sure what you are reporting. The Project Name is not used by any Google Cloud APIs. The APIs use either the Project ID or the Project Number. The Project Name is just a type of description for your use and not by Google Cloud. The Project ID must be unique in Google Cloud. The Project Name does not matter.

Comment: So is the document wrong? If I deleted a project and after 30 days, can I reuse the deleted project's ID?

Comment: By the way, "Note that you can't reuse the project name of a deleted project." does it mean the project ID instead of name?

Answer (score 2):

There is an slight error in the documentation :

The behavior is:
1. You can reuse the project name of an existing project, many times over.
2. You can reuse the project name of a deleted project.
3. You can reuse the project name of a deleted and purged project.

It is the reuse of Project IDs that is not an available option.

To clarify as I have previously written, even after the purge from the system, (30 days) you will still be unable to reuse the project id - it is permanently recorded in Google’s system.

Maybe I can help a little, I would like to let you know that there may be a better way to deal with this issue. It would probably be best if you create a variable in your system (called something like :  MY_CURRENT_PROJECT_ID) which is used anywhere that the project id is needed. This would mean that if the project id changed you would only have to  change it in one place.

I hope this helps.